# How do I search for a pip package by name only?

Tags: pip

By default pip searches both package names and descriptions. For some packages this results in a huge number of spurious hits and finding the one I actually want is a pain.

How I tell pip I want to search by name only?

Comment: On linux you can do something like this: `pip search numpy | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep numpy`

Comment: but you could use `yolk -S name=package_name`

Comment: @ziky Even better: `pip search numpy | awk '$1 == "numpy"'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment, because the current implementation (pip 8.1.1) does a `name OR summary` query [hard-coded in pip search command](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/6924faa/pip/commands/search.py#L60), though the [PyPI XML RPC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc) supports different queries.

Comment: and it is still the case for pip 10.0 https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/search.py#L65

Answer (score 9):

Well, on Linux/OSX not to hard to do something semi-manual with a bit of `grep`/`egrep` (OSX tends to require you to use egrep for regex, Linux doesn't).

The search below returns a lot of stuff (41 actually if you pip it through to `wc`).

`pip search psycopg`

first few lines of ouput:

```
gevent-psycopg2 (0.0.3)              - pip-installable package for patching psycopg2 to use gevent
django-psycopg2-pool (0.1.1)         - A db backend for Django using the gevent psycopg2-pool
pg4nosql (0.4.2)                     - A simple psycopg2 based wrapper for nosql like database interaction with python.
zope.psycopgda (1.1.1)               - Psycopg Database Adapter for Zope 3
qmarkpg (0.2)                        - A psycopg2 wrapper using the qmark parameters style
```

But if you look at the pip output you see that the packaname field tends to terminate with version names - *psycopg (1.1.21)*

So, write this instead:

`pip search psycopg | egrep "^.*psycopg.*\("`

output:

```
gevent-psycopg2 (0.0.3)              - pip-installable package for patching psycopg2 to use gevent
django-psycopg2-pool (0.1.1)         - A db backend for Django using the gevent psycopg2-pool
zope.psycopgda (1.1.1)               - Psycopg Database Adapter for Zope 3
psycopg2-managed-connection (1.0.0)  - Thread-safe connection manager for psycopg2 connections.
db-psycopg2 (0.0.7)                  - psycopg2 driver for db
kr-impatient-psycopg2 (2.5.2.dev0)   - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
tornado-psycopg2 (0.3.1)             - Tornado driver for support asynchronous mode for psycopg2.
psycopg2 (2.6.1)                     - psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
psycopg2-dateutils (0.1)             - Use dateutils.relativedelta to represent PostgreSQL interval types
psycopg2ct (2.4.4)                   - An implementation of the psycopg2 module using ctypes.
psycopgwrap (1.05)                   - A wrapper around psycopg2 to make common things easier.
psycopgda (1.0)                      - Psycopg Database Adapter for Zope 3
psycopg-postgis (0.1.1)              - Pyscopg helpers to work with PostGIS.
psycopg2cffi (2.7.2)                 - .. image:: https://travis-ci.org/chtd/psycopg2cffi.svg?branch=master
psycopg2cffi-compat (1.1)            - A Simple library to enable psycopg2 compatability
little_pger (0.65)                   - A thin layer just a tad above SQL, for use with PostgreSQL and psycopg2, when you want to wrap queries in a convenient way, using plain data structures (but you don't feel like using an ORM, for some reason).
psycopg (1.1.21)                     - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
psycopg2da (2.0.9)                   - Python psycopg2 database adapter for Zope
```

This assumes that there are no parenthesis within package name, of course.

as a reusable bash function (put in `.profile` or the like):

```
pipsearchpackagename(){
    #a bash function.
    pip search $1 | egrep "^.*"$1".*\("
}
```

Comment: To complement, when you need to search for the exact name of the package you can use like `pip search psycopg | egrep "^psycopg\ "`
(starts by the query string and doesn't contain any whitespaces).